# MySql find if an enum field contains an exact value

Tags: mysql, enums, resultset, workbench

I have a stored procedure that checks model compatibility and returns success or failure message. 
For example cpu and motherboard have to share the same socket. 
Possible values from all entries:

```
    cpu           mb                      case                          mb
+-----+----+ +-----+---+ +-----------------+-------------------+ +-------+-----+
|cpu_socket| |mb_socket| | case_size                           | |   mb_size   |  
|   AM4    | |   AM4   | |uATX/MicroATX,ATX,ExtendedATX,MiniITX| |uATX/MicroATX|
|   1151   | |   1151  | |uATX/MicroATX,MiniITX                | |     ATX     |
+-----+----+ +----+----+ +-----------------+-------------------+ +-------+-----+
```

case_size and mb_size are enum fields.

`IF (cpu_socket=mb_socket) then ....` or `IF (cpu_socket LIKE mb_socket) then ....`
will work for checking the socket.

But how can I check for motherboard size and case size? If i write:

`IF (case_size = mb_size) then ....` or
`IF (case_size LIKE '%mb_size%') then ....`
None of them works because when a motherboard has the 'ATX' value it will return cases with the value 'uATX/MicroATX,MiniITX' because it contains 'uATX'.

How can i check the compatibility for this field  ?

Comment: Are you really storing CSV string values in the `case_size` field?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen case_size is an enum field. I have an assignment that says I have to do it that way.

Comment: Nothing at all wrong with an enum field, but there is something wrong with defining one of the enum values as `uATX/MicroATX,MiniITX`.  This is not normalized data.

Comment: 'Nothing at all...' well - even that's debatable.

Comment: Note also that `case` is a reserved word.

Comment: @Strawberry I have it as pccase in my db.  My assignment has a hint: A pc case may have many possible sizes for a motherboard, so you have to check if a value belongs to a result set.

Comment: A 'result set' is not a comma delimited string